# Why browser-sync is not working with moodle theme

Tags: javascript, node.js, moodle, browser-sync

I am trying to using browser-sync with moodle theme, but I am not getting success for using it's features for moodle theme.

What I am trying to do is change the color by watching the css file.
So I have run below command from moodle root directory.

```
browser-sync start --proxy "http://localhost/moodle" --files "theme/clean/style/*.css"
```

Moodle's home page is opened in browser with showing 'browser-sync' is connected.
Now I changed the body's color at custom.css of clean theme.

The command prompt shows the `custom.css` file is changed but new color does not apply on moodle page without page refresh. The below image shows the changes of css file.

[image: browser-sync-connected]

What I am doing wrong? Is it possible to use browse-sync for moodle themes.

The browser-sync is working fine in simple php pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do apology for posting the answer of my own question.

Usually, in moodle we have listed out the css files in `config.php`. After created new css and listed this into `config.php` does not work. So I did attach the new css file into `head` tag with `link` tag, something like if I do create `mycss.css`

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/moodle/theme/clean/style/mycss.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

And run above `browser-sync` command which reflects the new css on browser without reload.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but try adding this to the config.php

```
$CFG->themedesignermode = true;
```

It turns off caching for the theme which is useful during design. Turn it off on production though because it will be very slow otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this one is not working also done `designer mode on` but not any effect.